# How to repeat a simple nonrmap in vim?

Tags: vim

I am trying to write slightly enhanced version of VIM’s mark function, which uses the combination of m and any capital letter to mark a file.

What I want to implement is, instead of using only a single letter, set a mark allowing the combination of two letters, so that if I have files named, test_views, test_models, test_forms, I could use tv, tm, and tf, then don’t have to bother what to map to which file.

What I come up with is so far is:

```
nnoremap <some-prefix>tv :let tv = expand("%")<cr>
nnoremap <leader>tv :execute 'edit' tv<cr>
```

but couldn’t figure out to write this more effectively. (I shouldn’t repeat this 26 * 26 times, should I?).

Creating function should be one way, but even if I could manage to finish writing this, I don’t think the usability would meet what I expect.

```
nnoremap , :call StoreFile(k_map)

fun! StoreFile(k_map)
    let k_map = expand("%”)
endfunl
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create all those mappings with a couple of `:help :for` loop:

```
let alphabet = split('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', '\zs')
for first_key in alphabet
    for second_key in alphabet
        let pair = first_key . second_key
        execute "nnoremap <Space>" . pair . " :<C-u>let " . pair . " = expand('%')<CR>"
        execute "nnoremap <leader>" . pair . " :execute 'edit '" . pair . "<cr>"
    endfor
endfor
```